# Laravel 5.6 Upgrade caused Logging to break

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.6

Heey!

So I've recently been given the task to take a Laravel 5.2 up to 5.6. It seemed to be fine...until I tried to do a `\Log::info()`. Every time I run that, I get a big error, but at the end, it still prints to the log. I saw the 5.6 documentation on creating the `config/logger.php`. I took a fresh copy of it from github. The only thing I did after that was set an env variable for the `LOG_CHANNEL` to be single. Here's the error I get:

> [2018-03-02 08:28:59] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at I:\xampp\htdocs\mtm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php:181)
>   [ ....

I did a file comparison between Laravel 5.2 and 5.6. I'm not seeing anything that jumps out that would break the Logging functionality.

Has anyone run into this with a Laravel upgrade?

Comment: Is `'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,` in your `aliases` in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes it is! I did confirm that. :) Good question.

Comment: Huh, very odd, then. What if you do a `Log::info` call in Tinker? Same error?

Comment: Yea. The Tinker outputs null and the laravel.EMERGENCY shows up in the error log.

Comment: I hope your error is already resolved. We had the same issue, and after debugging we found that APP_LOG_LEVEL needs to be all in lowercase. Unfortunately we add APP_LOG_LEVEL=ERROR, which was causing the issue

Comment: @jtanmay I just started out with a fresh install of Laravel 5.6. That fixed my issue. That's good to know in the future though!! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add this file to your config folder
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/config/logging.php

and add this to your .env file `LOG_CHANNEL=stack`

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:clear` command afterwards.

Comment: I have already added the logger.php as I mentioned. It was in the upgrade. I've tried the stack instead of single in the .env but both bring back the same error. Thanks for chiming in though!

Comment: @cbloss793 it's `logging.php` not `logger.php`. it solved my issue.

Comment: @AmitShah that might have been it. I ended up just starting out with a fresh version and moved the pieces over. Thanks though!!

Comment: That link is broken

Comment: updated link: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/config/logging.php

for me, I had to add the null driver since I had the logging.php file already
```
        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => NullHandler::class,
        ],

        'emergency' => [
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        ],
```

Answer (score 23):

I was facing the same issue due to upgrade of my laravel version from 5.3 to 5.7. But after search of few mints i found the solution. 
You just need to follow the following steps.

1. create logging.php file inside the **config** folder.
2. Copy code from this [Official Link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/config/logging.php) of Laravel.
3. Past this code into your logging.php file.
4. run this command -- php artisan config:clear

All done. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I did the same. I think I was missing more than that. A fresh install and move the files over worked the best. Thanks though! And welcome to Stack!! :)

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem and tried to do everything as you did but not work.

Finally, I've found that it was because of cached config, just clear it and everything will be fine:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently had the same error in my development machine (and not in the production one, oddly). In my development machine I have both `php 7.1` and `php 7.2` installed. Checking with `phpinfo()`, I discovered that 7.1 was the default version, so I decided to switch to 7.2.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

That didn't solve the problem (but maybe was part of it).

After several hours spent on trying everything suggested around the web, I found my solution by:

1. Checking all the permissions in the storage folder.
2. In my project folder, clearing all the cache(s) and config(s).
3. Dumping all composer autoload files.

In detail:

```
cd your_project_full_path
sudo chmod -R 0775 storage
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

After this, I had no problem any more. Maybe try 0755 as permission for the storage folder. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ohh! I appreciate you going into full detail! I am using PHP 7.1.7 which should have been fine according to the Laravel docs. Sadly, I'm on a Windows machine so the permissions is not an issue. I did do all the artisan clears you suggested and a composer dump. Still doesn't work. I wonder if I need to upgrade to PHP 7.2.

Comment: PS. I gave you a vote up for a completely thorough answer. I know that will help someone. Just didn't work in my case.

Comment: Thank you for you vote :) Anyway, if you are still struggling with it, another test you could do is to try creating a new app: if you still have that problem, maybe it's a matter of environment, otherwise should be an issue related to your current upgrade itself (from 5.2 to 5.6 the jump is huge!).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. This is the first 5.6 app that I've got. I'm on other 5.5 and they are fine. This is the first massive update app I've done. I almost just created a new app and moved pieces over, but I didn't start this app and there was a lot of customized stuff. I may still do that. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: I spent three hours on this, you had the right answer! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

use [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) , and add `logging.php` to your config files.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I did that. Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 4):

After two days of some research, I found a solution on Github.

If you are using Laravel 5.5.4 to Laravel 5.6.*, then you can just install and configure the exceptions package by Graham Campbell.

Link: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions

This worked perfectly for me on Mac OSX (PHP 7.1.7), Laravel 5.6.22

My initial error:

```
2018-05-25 14:35:07] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger.
```

`Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /Users/pro/Sites/metiwave/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:181)`

Comment: Good find! I'll have to try this on my old project and let you know if it worked for me. I ended up just using a fresh install of Laravel 5.6 and moving the pieces over. It made things so much cleaner. I am curious if it works though! +1 for researching!

Comment: @cbloss793 I am certain it will work for you because you will get to see the error on the application and fix it easily. Thanks for the thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `APP_LOG=`  was blank in **.env** file so I saved it as `APP_LOG=single` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out I had accidentally moved the config folder. If you find yourself in the same situation, (probably as embarrassed as I am) move it back to the root folder of your project.

Regards

Comment: I won't lie, this made me laugh. We've all done silly things like this. :) Good on you to find it!

Answer (score 0):

all right, i got it
take a look at the official library, copy log config configuration code ：

link ：https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/config/logging.php

create in your project's config directory logging.php file
copy the code in

clear the cache ：php artisan config:clear

that's it. keep stomping ...

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement**

[2023-03-10 09:41:21] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/5835934853094/domains/--------.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)

**Solution 100% Work**

1. This Problem is due to Cache and php version.
2. You need remove cache from
3. storage/Framework/views/
4. storage/Framework/session/
5. storage/Framework/cache/
6. **You need upgrade to php version 8.1 if you are using laravel 9.19 or
   above**

Answer (score 0):

In case someone reaches here just like I did.

After upgrading the legacy application from Lumen 6 to Lumen 10 and PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.3, I faced the same issue.

On Lumen 10 (since Lumen 8.x), [it started logging deprecations as deprecations instead of exceptions](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/commit/529d0a9d18cbfc19c71ab80131eeb2c22b60def3)

For logging deprecations, it tries to log it to a different channel based on the configuration. However the config file is too old, and the log channel does not exist in the configuration. That's why [it creates an emergency logger](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1d0f002172d1570389e72fb474d16a6996fc943d/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php#L134-L147) that was luckily pointed to my `single` driver's path.

I hope this explains the issue and the next person who reaches here will [get a hint](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#logging-deprecation-warnings).