# Cannot start server using php artisan. Receiving laravel.Emergency Unable to create configured logger

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-artisan

I'm still relatively new to laravel. I created a working website in Laravel 6 during December 2019 and put it into production. Today (April 8th) I opened the project in VS code and started the terminal view and typed in php artisan serve to load the server and view the site on my local environment to look at some changes i want to make but the server did not start and I was returned the error

```
In RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php line 48:

  Directory name must not be empty.
```

I have been trying to find reasons for this and solutions through various forums but struggling to get anywhere. my project laravel.log has logged the following.

```
[2020-04-08 12:00:43] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php:184)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php(118): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve(NULL)
#1 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php(98): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get(NULL)
#2 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php(539): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#3 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(118): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error('Directory name ...', Array)
#4 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(RuntimeException))
#5 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(376): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(RuntimeException))
#6 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->reportException(Object(RuntimeException))
#7 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"} 
[2020-04-08 12:00:43] laravel.ERROR: Directory name must not be empty. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Directory name must not be empty. at C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:48)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php(48): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('', 4096)
#1 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Finder.php(744): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Iterator\\RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('', 4096, false)
#2 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\symfony\\finder\\Finder.php(626): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->searchInDirectory('')
#3 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->getIterator()
#4 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(65): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#5 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#6 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(211): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#7 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#8 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#9 C:\\Imad\\Projects\\2019\\New\\burnz\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#10 {main}
"}
```

I don't undertand what variable is missing that should be in "log[]" where it says "Log [] is not defined".  Is anyone able to suggest anything or direct me to a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073558/laravel-5-6-upgrade-caused-logging-to-break might be of some help

Comment: Thanks Aynber. I tried so many things which didnt work so following someone's workaround I started a fresh build and copied everything across when i realised my config folder somehow had moved into a sibling folder and become invisible to the project. My problem is now solved. Such a silly mistake, dont know how it happened.